# Exec in a function SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table where i am storing multiple values like below,

| ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Book1 | Author1 | Station1 |
| Book2 | Author2 | Station1 |
| Book3 | Author3 | Station3 |

Now i wanted to have all books grouped by a particular station in a single row like below

| Book1 | Book2 | Book3 | Station |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Author1 | Author2 | NULL | Station1 |
| NULL | NULL | Station2 | Station2 |

Now i have achieved this using following XML approach

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX), @query NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @cols = STUFF(
             (
                 SELECT DISTINCT
                        ','+QUOTENAME(books.ColumnA)
                 FROM [dbo].[Books] books FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
             ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '');
SET @query = 'SELECT [ColumnC], '+@cols+'from (SELECT [ColumnC],
       [ColumnB] AS [Author],
       [ColumnA] AS [BookCols]
FROM [dbo].[Books]
)x pivot (max(Author) for BookCols in ('+@cols+')) p';
```

I am facing challenge to use this in any function or View as i have another complex query and I have to use this query within that query to have a single dataset.
What is the best approach to use above in a select statement.

Comment: You can't. A function cannot use `EXEC`, and a `VIEW` must be well defined; it's just a pseudo table defined by a `SELECT`. Ideally leave dynamic pivoting to your reporting layer.

Comment: Obligatory note: SQL Server 2008 has been completely unsupported since mid 2020; it is *long* past time you got your upgrade path sorted.

Comment: To follow up on upgrading away from Sql Server 2008. Not only will this get you off that unpatched (therefore insecure) version of Sql Server, but it will also directly address this issue by letting you simplify some of ugly `STUFF()/FOR XML` code with the newer, easier, and faster  `STRING_AGG()` instead.

Comment: What I posted below should do the trick. The only nuance is that I didn't see you on SQL 2008 where CONCAT is not available. You can just use `'string'+@variable` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you are using to create your query (@query) is called [Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-stored-procedures/sql-server-dynamic-sql/) (AKA `dSQL`).
You cannot use DSQL in a function, you need to use a *stored procedure*.

Here's a simple table valued function; I'm taking a number(@N) and adding 1 to it via Dynamic SQL. The correct syntax would be:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnPlusOne(@N INT)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN

  EXEC(CONCAT('SELECT 1+',@N));
GO
```

This returns this error:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure fnPlusOne, Line 4 [Batch Start Line 2]
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXEC'.
```

With a function you need to define what columns or atomic values, including the data type for each. When you use Dynamic SQL there is no way for SQL Server to know what to return because, with DSQL, you can return anything.

A stored procedure, on the other hand, can run DSQL. Here's the same logic as a stored proc:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.PlusOne @N INT
AS
  DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX) = CONCAT('SELECT 1+',@N);
  
  EXEC(@query);
GO
```

You would execute like so:

```
EXEC dbo.PlusOne 10;
```

Your proc would look something like this (I can't test this though):

```
CREATE PROC dbo.yourproc AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(MAX), @query NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @cols = STUFF(
                 (
                     SELECT DISTINCT
                            ','+QUOTENAME(books.ColumnA)
                     FROM [dbo].[Books] books FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                 ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '');
    SET @query = 'SELECT [ColumnC], '+@cols+'from (SELECT [ColumnC],
           [ColumnB] AS [Author],
           [ColumnA] AS [BookCols]
    FROM [dbo].[Books]
    )x pivot (max(Author) for BookCols in ('+@cols+')) p';
END
GO
```